# Corona SDK. Lua. display.newText() - my updated score text is overlapping old one without erasing

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I'm developing clone version of Nintendo Tetris game using Corona SDK. There are two text objects on the top of my screen: one represents current level, another one represents current score. Every time I fill in line with blocks my program erases this line and add some scores and +1 level. The problem is that once I update my score and level variables and use myText.text to refresh my texts it doesn't erase old text and creates the new text that overlapping the old one.

My code is following:
1) I declare two local variables at the begging of my scene

```
local scoreText
local levelText
```

2) I have function that erases the line and updates texts

```
function eraseLines()
            -- some code that erases lines
            scores = scores + 10
            scoreText.text = "Score:"..scores
            level = level + 1
            levelText.text = "Level:"..level
end
```

3) In scene:show(event) I create our texts

```
function scene:show( event )
    -- some code    
    scoreText = display.newText("Score:"..scores, halfW*0.5, 20 )
    levelText = display.newText("Level:".. level, halfW*1.5, 20 )
    sceneGroup:insert( scoreText )
    sceneGroup:insert( levelText )
    scoreText:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )
    levelText:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )
end
```

Please help me to find out why overlapping happens

Comment: do you call scene:show(event) multiple times by any chance?
Also eraseLines is a pretty bad name for a function that updates a text.
Why not name it updateScoreLevel or something to avoid confusion

Comment: @Piglet 1) I call scene:show(event) only once. There are two phase in this event: "will" and "did". When I was posing my question my code was executed at "will" phase. Then I cut and pasted it into "did" phase and overlapping doesn't happen anymore. I'm not sure why it works this way. 2) the function eraseLines does erase lines of Tetris blocks on the screen and updates text. Probably it's better exclude text manipulation form there and make it as a separate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you are adding twice score/level labels, 'cause the show event is called two times (phases) `will` and `did`. Add display objects when you are creating the scene.

```
-- create()
function scene:create( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    -- Code here runs when the scene is first created but has not yet appeared on screen
    scoreText = display.newText( "Score: 0", halfW * 0.5, 20 )
    levelText = display.newText( "Level: 0", halfW * 1.5, 20 )
    sceneGroup:insert( scoreText )
    sceneGroup:insert( levelText )
    scoreText:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )
    levelText:setFillColor( 0, 0, 0 )

end


-- show()
function scene:show( event )

    local sceneGroup = self.view
    local phase = event.phase

    if ( phase == "will" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is still off screen (but is about to come on screen)
        scoreText.text = "Score: " .. score
        levelText.text = "Level: " .. level

    elseif ( phase == "did" ) then
        -- Code here runs when the scene is entirely on screen

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a poorly constructed single script for displaying score

```
    local scoreCounter = {}
    local frameTime = 0
    scoreCount = 0
    finalScore = nil
    local tempText = nil

    local function update( event )
         frameTime = frameTime + 1

         --after every 7 frames score will increase
         if(frameTime % 7 == 0) then
            scoreCount = scoreCount + 1
            tempText.text = scoreCount 
            frameTime = 0
         end
    end

    -- here is a memory leak I guess
    function scoreCounter.displayScore(xCoordinate, yCoordinate)
        tempText = display.newText(scoreCount, xCoordinate, yCoordinate)
    end

    Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", update)

    return scoreCounter
```

Usage:

```
local scoreCounter = require("pathtoluafile")
scoreCounter.displayScore(xCoordinate, yCoordinate)
```